# Manually converting a char to an int - Strange behaviour

Tags: c++

I've wrote a small program to convert a char to an int. The program reads in chars of the form `'1234'` and then outputs the int `1234`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Enter a number with as many digits as you like: ";
    char digit_char = cin.get(); // Read in the first char
    int number = digit_char - '0';
    digit_char = cin.get(); // Read in the next number
    while(digit_char != ' '){ // While there is another number
        // Shift the number to the left one place, add new number
        number = number * 10 + (digit_char - '0');
        digit_char = cin.get(); // Read the next number
    }
cout << "Number entered: " << number << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This works fine with small chars, but if I try a big char (length 11 and above) like `12345678901` the program returns the wrong result, `-539222987`.

What's going on?

Comment: What size is an `int` on your system and what is the maximum value on your system an `int` can hold?

Comment: Hint: What's the biggest number that can be stored in an int?

Comment: It's shouldn't be "strange" anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `int` is not wide enough to store such big numbers. Try to use `unsigned long long int` instead of the type `int`.

You can check what maximum number can be represented in the given integer type. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max() << std::endl;
}
```

In C you can use constant `ULLONG_MAX` defined in header `<limits.h>`

Answer (score 3):

12345678901 in binary is 34 bits. As a result, you overflowed the integer value and set the sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `int`, try to use `unsigned long long int` for your variable ***number***.
That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Overflowed integer. Use unsigned long long int.